# Table column has to be updated once its exceed in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am using 'sqlite' as a backend for the application. I have a table called 'student' and it has columns like student-name,student-id,student-year-of-join(with date and time),student-passed-out(with date and time),student-status. I insert student-name,student-id,student-year-of-join,student-passed-out in the starting itself. Once the student-passed-out from the college automatically the student-status has to be update to 'passed out'.

I tried using the sqlite trigger,it's not working properly

```
create trigger student-passed-out after update on student when student-passed-out<=datetime(now)begin update set candidate_status='Passed'
```

Here the student joins in different date and time. 
What I want is once the student passed out time is expired or exceeded the status should change.

Answer (score 1):

As per [sqlite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html):

> Both the WHEN clause and the trigger actions may access elements of
>   the row being inserted, deleted or updated using references of the
>   form "NEW.column-name" and "OLD.column-name", where column-name is the
>   name of a column from the table that the trigger is associated with.
>   OLD and NEW references may only be used in triggers on events for
>   which they are relevant, as follows:
>
> INSERT    NEW references are valid
>
> UPDATE    NEW and OLD references are valid
>
> DELETE    OLD references are
>   valid

The column name in the `WHEN` clause requires a `NEW.` or `OLD.` prefix.

Speaking of column names, using `-` in the column name is going to create a lot of work for you. The names will always have to be quoted, otherwise the `-`can be interpreted as a minus sign.

The `update` clause in the trigger is missing a table name (and likely a `WHERE` clause, as written it will update *every row in the table*).

--ADDENDA--

- a `before update` trigger executes, obviously, before the record is updated in the database. But what happens next? The "actual" update happens. In this case the `candidate_status` column *will change back* to what it was before the trigger ran. Perhaps try `after update` trigger.
- the syntax for the current date/time is `datetime('now')`
- This `update set candidate_status='PASSED';` is missing a table name *and a WHERE clause*. Without a WHERE clause, it will update *every row in the table*. Perhaps something like `WHERE student_id = OLD.student_id` is what you need.

Comment: Hi ,I have tried this query create trigger end_time_trigger before update on student when old.student_passed_out<=datetime(now) begin update set candidate_status='PASSED'; end;. I am getting error on 'syntax error -near set'. As you mentioned I changed column name with '_' underscore

Comment: more details added to answer